# Django - DEV django bulk update/add m2m field ... how to exactly?

Tags: django

I need to bulk add m2m fields and looks like django dev version [supports bulk.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)

But they only give example of how to add a single object? I cant find any examples of it being done in bulk.

Also is this method more effective then solution [proposed here?](http://grokbase.com/p/gg/django-users/158c66e3vp/bulk-add-m2m-relationship-for-multiple-instances)

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/django-users/158c8q3ty3/bulk-add-m2m-relationship-for-multiple-instances (